# update merge path in word doc

Tags: merge, ms-word

I have 2000 documents which were created by an incorrectly configured application which now uses an invalid merge data path.

e.g. c:\APPNAME\WP\MERGE.TXT

The files now live in H:\MERGE.TXT so all users can access them.

Is there a way to update this path without opening each file in MS Word and reselecting the data source?

Looking forward to your replies.

Comment: macro, which you could write, will still require doc file to be opened. However, this could be done then (quite) quickly without your additional input. Try with macrorecoder first- what you get if you record operation for any chosen file.

Comment: There are potentially two problems using VBA to do this. If the original data source is no longer there, you will see a popup that (may) contain the name of the data source. If you set Application.DisplayAlerts to wdAlertsNone to avoid seeing 2000 popups, Word opens the document with no data source, so you cannot then determine the original data source name. In other words, you may need to click through 2000 "file open" operations to discover the correct data source for each document. Even if you do that, recent versions of Word frequently report the name of a temp file, not the original. Bad.

Comment: OTOH, if they are .docx files, ou may be able to do this via C# or VB.NET and the Open XML SDK. There's some code at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8b363660-cc7f-4b7d-addf-30df57a0ecd6 that shows how to remove an existing data source but not how to replace it (reliably). i.e., if it's .docx, I suggest you have a look around for a better code sample.